# C# user defined exception

Tags: c#, .net

Is it necessary to declare a class in 'public ' visibility mode if the class is defining the user defined exception which extends System.exception  class in C#?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Yes it needs to be Public

Comment: It would be customary but by no means necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It entirely dependes on how you want to use your user defined exception class.

The concept of access modifier is not related at all with the idea of a user defined exception.

A user defined exception is just a user defined class which extends System.Exception, while an access modifier is a construct which specifies the visibility of that class with respect to the client code.

This means that if you just want to use your custom exception class inside the defining assembly you can simply define it as an internal class. 
Of course this won't be very useful, because you usually define custom exception class inside class libraries and you want them to be visible in any assembly referencing your class library, so that a consumer can have a chance to handle your custom exception class if it makes sense in his or hers client code.

Answer (score 1):

[Try it on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Au8ryD) and see:

```
public class Foo
{
    private class MyException : Exception
    {
        public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
    }

    public static void Throw()
    {
        throw new MyException("Hello world.");
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Foo.Throw();
        }
        //catch(Foo.MyException myException)
        //{
        //     This doesn't compile
        //}
        catch(System.Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine
            (
                "Exception is of type '{0}' with a message of '{1}'", 
                exception.GetType().Name, 
                exception.Message
            );
            //Does not compile:
            //var typedException = (Foo.MyException)exception;  
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception is of type 'MyException' with a message of 'Hello world.'
```

So it turns out you can still catch the exception, inspect its type, and read its base properties, and everything works. But if you want to handle it in a type-safe way and cast it to the specific type, your code won't compile. This also means you can't use a type-specific `catch` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace EXP7{
    public class InsufficientBalanceException : Exception
    {
        public InsufficientBalanceException(string msg) : base(msg)
{}
}
public class UserDefinedException
{
        double minbal;
        double balance;
        double withdraw;
        public UserDefinedException(double m, double b, double w)
        {
            minbal = m;
            balance = b;
            withdraw = w;
        }
        public void checkBalance() {
        try
        {
            if ((balance == minbal) && (withdraw <= minbal || withdraw > minbal))
            {
                throw new InsufficientBalanceException("Withdraw amount cannot be less than or equal to minimum balance!");
            }
            else {
            
            balance -= withdraw;
            Console.WriteLine("New balance: "+balance);
            }
        }
        catch (InsufficientBalanceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine($"Current balance:{balance} ");
        }
    }
}
    class Program {
    public static void Main(string [] args) {
        UserDefinedException obj = new UserDefinedException(1000, 1000, 2000);
        obj.checkBalance();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
namespace bankbalance{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double balance = 1000;
        Console.Write("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
        double withdrawAmount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        try
        {
            if (withdrawAmount > balance)
            {
                throw new Exception("Withdraw amount cannot be greater than balance!");
            }
            balance -= withdrawAmount;
            Console.WriteLine("New balance: "+balance);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine($"Current balance:{balance} ");
        }
    }
}
}
```

//code by kamalesh & sharad

Comment: Um ... this just demonstrates throwing and catching an exception. There is nothing that answers OP's question about whether or not a custom exception needs to be public.